# Reportviewer print button works only in localhost

Tags: asp.net, .net, reportviewer, rdlc

I have reportviewer control for manipulating with rdlc reports. Now everything works fine when i run application on localhost. Problem is when I run application from server, print button doesn't do anything. It acting like there is no any functionality for it.
Also to mention this is problem when i use IE browser(IE 9).
Does any one know why is this happening and how to solve this problem?
For any more info about problem leave a comment, please.

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it, problem actually was with some IE add on. So if anyone else got the same problem you can try this.